# Getting Error: "Error converting data type nvarchar to numeric" in SQL

Tags: c#, sql, web-services, sql-server-2008

I am passing 4 Parameters to an asp.net Webservice. This is my Code so far:

Webmethod:

```
    [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
    [WebMethod]
    public List<RaumHelper.RAUM> Raum(string RAUMKLASSE_ID, string STADT_ID, string GEBAEUDE_ID, string REGION_ID)
    {
        return RaumHelper.Raum(RAUMKLASSE_ID, STADT_ID, GEBAEUDE_ID, REGION_ID);
    }
```

Helperclass:

```
   public class RaumHelper
            {
                public class RAUM
                {
                    public string RaumName { get; set; }
                    public string RaumID { get; set; }

                }

                internal static List<RAUM> Raum( string RAUMKLASSE_ID, string STADT_ID, string GEBAEUDE_ID, string REGION_ID)
                {
                    List<RAUM> strasseObject = new List<RAUM>();

                    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=Localhost\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=BOOK-IT-V2;Integrated Security=true;"))
                    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(@"SELECT r.BEZEICHNUNG AS BEZEICHNUNG, r.ID AS ID FROM RAUM r WHERE RAUMKLASSE_ID = @Raumklasse_ID OR STADT_ID = @Stadt_ID OR GEBAEUDE_ID = @Gebaeude_ID OR REGION_ID = @Region_ID", con)) 
                    {


                        con.Open();
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Raumklasse_ID", RAUMKLASSE_ID);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Stadt_ID", STADT_ID);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Gebaeude_ID", GEBAEUDE_ID);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Region_ID", REGION_ID);



                        using (SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                        {



                            while (rdr.Read())
                            {



                                if (rdr["BEZEICHNUNG"] != DBNull.Value && rdr["ID"] != DBNull.Value)
                                {

                                    strasseObject.Add(new RAUM()
                                    {
                                        RaumName = rdr["BEZEICHNUNG"].ToString(),
                                        RaumID = rdr["ID"].ToString()

                                    });
                                }

                            }
                        }
                    }
                    return strasseObject;
                }

            }
```

If i invoke that Webmethod with the 4 Parameters, the Method is working fine an i get a LIST of the RaumName's and RaumID's. But if i put only one Parameter iam getting an Error:

```
    System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Error converting data type nvarchar to numeric.
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Run(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.HasMoreRows()
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.ReadInternal(Boolean setTimeout)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.Read()
```

The ID's in the Database are stored as Numeric and i passing string. I think that is the problem. But i dont know how to fix this.

I also want that my Query works also with only two or three entered Parameters.

Thank in advance!

Comment: define the data type and default value for the parameters, it shall resolve the issue.

Comment: Where is the WebMethod? Does it have any default values for missing parameters?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Usually it's not a problem to pass a `string` to a parameter that's numeric, as long as the SQL Server is able to convert the content of the string to a numeric value itself. If that doesn't work, you get this error.

For example: Passing `"Hello"` to a parameter that's numeric, you get an error. Passing `"1234"` you don't. Please note that an empty string or a string containing whitespace can not be converted to a numeric value!

However, it should be said that it is not good style to do that. You should make sure that the types you use in your application match the types in the database to avoid problems. Maybe some further detail on why you need to have `string` types in your application could help.

**EDIT 1**
To make a parameter optional for the query, the way to go would be the following:

1. Change your SQL statement to allow optional parameters like `WHERE RAUMKLASSE_ID = ISNULL(@Raumklasse_ID, RAUMKLASSE_ID)`.
2. Do not add the `@Raumklasse_ID` parameter if it should be optional or add the value `DBNull.Value`

You should really consider changing your `string` properties to nullable types like `int?`.

**EDIT 2**
This is how your code could look implementing the changes I suggested in Edit 1:

```
using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(@"SELECT r.BEZEICHNUNG AS BEZEICHNUNG, r.ID AS ID FROM RAUM r WHERE RAUMKLASSE_ID = ISNULL(@Raumklasse_ID, RAUMKLASSE_ID) OR STADT_ID = ISNULL(@Stadt_ID, STADT_ID) OR GEBAEUDE_ID = ISNULL(@Gebaeude_ID, GEBAEUDE_ID) OR REGION_ID = ISNULL(@Region_ID, REGION_ID)", con)) 
{
    con.Open();
    if (!String.IsNullOrWhitespace(RAUMKLASSE_ID))
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Raumklasse_ID", RAUMKLASSE_ID);
    else
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Raumklasse_ID", DBNull.Value);
    if (!String.IsNullOrWhitespace(STADT_ID))
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Stadt_ID", STADT_ID);
    else
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Stadt_ID", DBNull.Value);
    if (!String.IsNullOrWhitespace(GEBAEUDE_ID))
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Gebaeude_ID", GEBAEUDE_ID);
    else
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Gebaeude_ID", DBNull.Value);
    if (!String.IsNullOrWhitespace(REGION_ID))
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Region_ID", REGION_ID);
    else
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Region_ID", DBNull.Value);
    ...
}
```

Comment: I've made an edit to my answer to show how to make parameters optional.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I appreciate that :). It works like charm now. But can you explain what the "else" is doing, i dont get it  actually

Comment: The `else` adds a parameter of the given name to the query, but assigns to it the value `null` of the SQL server (actually `null` in C# and `null` in SQL Server are different). This is to make sure that the parameter is provided to the query, but is `null`. While for calls to stored procedures the code would also work without the `else` branches if the parameters were declared to have the default value `null` in SQL, I'm not sure whether it'd work without the `else` branch in your case. You might get an error saying the parameter X was expected but not provided.

Comment: ah ok, in unterstand. Thanks for help again!

Comment: Pleasure - just let me add that I'd *really* recommend you change the ID properties from `string` to `int?`! If you can't pass `int?` to the web method for whatever reason, at least declare local `int?` variables within the method and cast the parameters like `int? localRaumID = String.IsNullOrWhitespace(RAUM_ID) ? (int?)null : Convert.ToInt32(RAUM_ID);`?

Answer (score 0):

The problem might be that you're not giving anything to infer the data type from as you're not setting the value of the parameter.

Try setting the parameters using the Add method as follows:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@Raumklasse_ID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = RAUMKLASSE_ID;
```

That way if you don't want to set the value, you can still define the parameter.

See here for more: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wbys3e9s

Answer (score 0):

Convert your string to intger type

```
 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Raumklasse_ID", Convert.ToInt32(RAUMKLASSE_ID));
 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Stadt_ID", Convert.ToInt32(STADT_ID));
 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Gebaeude_ID", Convert.ToInt32(GEBAEUDE_ID));
 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Region_ID", Convert.ToInt32(REGION_ID));
```

Comment: I tried your Solution. But no iam getting another Error: System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.

Comment: @Paks: That means you are passing a non stringble format to the Convert.Int32 function. So i guess the values in your variables are NULL. Use visual studio breakpoitns to see which variable value is null

Answer (score 0):

Do like this

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@Raumklasse_ID", SqlDbType.Int);// use here your SQL DataType, if it is numberic than use Numeric.
cmd.Parameters[0].value = Convert.ToInt32(RAUMKLASSE_ID);
```