# Error converting data type nvarchar to numeric

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, t-sql, ado.net

I used the following statement for a parameter.

```
comm.Parameters.Add("@name", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50).Value = txtname.Text;
```

`Name` is a SQL Server `nvarchar` column but I get this error:

> *Error converting data type nvarchar to numeric.*

My sql:

```
SqlCommand comm = conn.CreateCommand();
comm.CommandText = "execute addName @name";
comm.Parameters.Add("@name", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50).Value = txtname.Text;

conn.Open();
comm.ExecuteNonQuery();
conn.Close();
```

Can help my to fix this problem?
My store procedure:

```
USE [info]
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER procedure [dbo].[addName]
            @id numeric(18,0) = 0,
            @name nchar(50)
as
if (select name from TName where name = @name) is null
begin
select @id =  MAX(id)+1 from TName
insert into TName
values (@id, @name)
print @id
end
else
begin
print 'Eroare'
end
```

Comment: Maybe this can help you [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11014322/getting-error-error-converting-data-type-nvarchar-to-numeric-in-sql][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11014322/getting-error-error-converting-data-type-nvarchar-to-numeric-in-sql

Comment: What does `addName` do? It looks like `addName` has a numeric parameter and you're trying to give it an nvarchar that cannot be converted to numeric.

Comment: @MMK How will that help?

Comment: What is the signature of `addName`? What is the type of `@name` in the stored procedure? Could this error be happening inside the stored procedure, due to simply being: a bug?

Comment: @MMK that won't help at all in a *numeric* conversion

Comment: What is the datatype of your name column?

Comment: @Asif see the question: "`Name` is a SQL Server  `nvarchar` column". I guess the important question, however, is: what is the data type of the `@name` parameter

Comment: It's very likely that the problem is in the code of addName. Can you post it?

Comment: @MarcGravell: yes you are right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the edit, with the signature:

```
ALTER procedure [dbo].[addName]
        @id numeric(18,0) = 0,
        @name nchar(50)
```

then the problem becomes clear:

```
execute addName @name
```

is pass-by-position - so you are passing the value of `@name` into the `@id` parameter. If you were calling this from TSQL, to pass-by-name you need to use:

```
execute addName @name = @name
```

The first (left) states the parameter name, the second (right) states the value to use for this parameter; for example, to pass a literal into `addName`'s `@name` parameter:

```
execute addName @name = 'Fred'
```

However, from ADO.NET, a better approach is:

```
comm.CommandText = "addName";
comm.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
```

which automatically treats it as an SP-exec using pass-by-name.

Answer (score 0):

You must modify the type of your parameter `name` in your `addName` procedure, and set to `NVarChar`

You pass in C# NVarChar type, but you have numeric who is asked in procedure

Comment: thanks, in procedure I have _@id numeric(18,0) = 0_ and _@name nvarchar(50)_, I place @name first and it works

Comment: @Igor that works, but for all the wrong reasons. It will also break any other code that uses `addName` by-order. I **really** think you should be passing by-name here, not by-position. Changing the order of the parameters to fix this screams: "I'm doing it wrong", IMO.